# cakephp database connection with ip

Tags: cakephp, database-connection

Hi I have a site develop in cakephp.
I want to connect my cakephp to a database with an ip because me and my friends working together into the same network
My ip is:192.168.0.3
Ip of database into the second pc: 192.168.0.4

I can ping 192.168.0.4
Into the second pc running xampp mysql into the system.

This is my database configuration:

```
public $default = array (
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '192.168.0.4',
        'login' => 'login',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database',
        'prefix' => ''
    );
```

But gives me an error:
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.4' (10061) requires a database connection
ANd into the second pc this error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61 requires a database connection

Pc1 and pc2 doesn't work but, if pc2 (where is located database) write into database config into the host: localhost, it works. Me not.
How can I solve that?

Comment: can you connect with the mysql command line or any other client? Is you database configured at a standard port? have you tried using `'host' => '192.168.0.4:port'`?

Comment: no nothing  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.0.4:3306' (11004) requires a database connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `xampp on Windows`, then you can resolve it by editing file `your-xampppath\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`

and find the below tag

```
# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

and add

```
"Allow from all"
```

after Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 {line}

restart xampp
and you are done !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL config file (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) for the `skip-networking` option, which is enabled by default. Comment it out and restart MySQL.